# Why is my SparkSL shader code behaving differently with and without an if statement with an unreachable condition?

Tags: shader, fragment-shader, spark-ar-studio, sparksl

I'm writing a shader for Meta Spark Studio which creates a wavy pattern:

```
vec4 wavy(function<vec4(vec2)> tex, float waveAmplitude, float waveFrequency, float timeMultiplier) {
    vec2 coords = getVertexTexCoord();
    float time = getTime() * timeMultiplier;
    
    if(false && coords.x < -1.0){
        return tex(coords);
    }else{
        coords.y += cos(((coords.x * 3.14 * 5.0) + time * 3.14) * waveFrequency + time) * waveAmplitude * 1.0;
        return tex(coords);
    }
}
```

This code works as expected (I reached this weird state by trial and error), running the `else` clause and displaying correctly. The code block in `if` clause of the statement should never be executed anyway, so I can remove it and simplify as:

```
vec4 wavy(function<vec4(vec2)> tex, float waveAmplitude, float waveFrequency, float timeMultiplier) {
    vec2 coords = getVertexTexCoord();
    float time = getTime() * timeMultiplier;
    
    coords.y += cos(((coords.x * 3.14 * 5.0) + time * 3.14) * waveFrequency + time) * waveAmplitude * 1.0;
    return tex(coords);
}
```

However, the moment I do this, my effect behaves differently as if argument of `cos` is never multiplied by any number and the result is just different whatever I do.

Why is my code behaving only correctly whenever it's inside of an `else` block of an if statement with the `if` clause that always evaluates to false with no side effects, but incorrectly without that statement?